# GetFileAttributes in NTFS

Tags: ntfs

i want to use a windows API to check a file/directory is hidden or not . 
  GetFileAttributes may the best choice. but when i check the FAT "C:\", it's return 0x10.it's looks work well. but in NTFS "C:\" it's return 0x16, maybe it's show that  "C:\"'S Attribute is "system", "directory",and "hidden". so the problem is here, why it's return hidden? in fact it's not hidden.

would you please give me another API to check the windows file system's file/directory is hidden or not?
   thanks a lot.

Comment: Checking the root directory of a drive is not going to generally be a good test - attributes on the root may have different meanings

Comment: but the file/directory is chose by user, i don't want to write a special judge to solve this problem. and there is no other useful API?

Answer (score 0):

GetFileAttributes has a BIG BUG, to see it try this simple code:

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetFileAttributes(PChar('C:\.MyNonExistantFile'))));
```

It shows that GetFileAttributes has return 32 in decimal (since file does not exists it is a BUG, correct return value must be -1).

Also you can try it with this:

```
CreateDir('C:\.Anything');
ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetFileAttributes(PChar('C:\.Anything\MyNonExistantFile.TXT'))));
```

It is related with files and directories starting by a period (.) symbol.

Note: FileExists also returns true in that situations (and file does not exists).